# How to get Azure pipeline Task Status for a specific task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

My purpose is to get the status of a specific pipeline task in a job.

I've tried to send an API call referencing the method at the [Reference Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-task-log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) but it only returned the running log of the task.

Is there exist any method to get the status information of a a pipeline task?
Can we achieve to get status foe one task?

Any suggestions and directives is appreciated.

Comment: ae you trying to get from another pipeline or from within the same pipeline ?

Comment: Trying to get the status within the same pipeline.

Comment: could you share you existing pipeline please ?

Comment: Hi Hilal, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For release pipeline, I think this API should meet your requirements:

`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/Release/releases/<Release ID>?api-version=6.0-preview.6`

Sample response:

```
{
    ...,
    "environments": [
        {
            ...,
            },
            "deploySteps": [
                {...,
                    "releaseDeployPhases": [
                        {...,
                            "deploymentJobs": [
                                {
                                    "job": {
                                        "id": 8,
                                        "timelineRecordId": "9a737f0c-559e-5660-b520-9a7c39e93149",
                                        "name": "Agent job",
                                        "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:39.81Z",
                                        "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2633333Z",
                                        "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:39.81Z",
                                        "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2633333Z",
                                        "status": "failed",
                                        "rank": 1,
                                        "issues": [],
                                        "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                        "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/37/environments/37/deployPhases/41/tasks/8/logs"
                                    },
                                    "tasks": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 4,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "0f34296d-9707-4f4e-a489-e841851c4f47",
                                            "name": "Initialize job",
                                            "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:40.1733333Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:41.7833333Z",
                                            "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:40.1733333Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:41.7833333Z",
                                            "status": "succeeded",
                                            "rank": 1,
                                            "issues": [],
                                            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/37/environments/37/deployPhases/41/tasks/4/logs"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": 5,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "f9eb04f6-a1bd-4d30-86ed-d32704f0f6ec",
                                            "name": "Download Artifacts",
                                            "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:41.7933333Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:42.5233333Z",
                                            "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:41.7933333Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:42.5233333Z",
                                            "status": "succeeded",
                                            "rank": 2,
                                            "issues": [],
                                            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/37/environments/37/deployPhases/41/tasks/5/logs"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": 6,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "ee21b6e5-e611-5d0a-7967-2a6e400a3b0f",
                                            "name": "Extract files ",
                                            "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:42.5233333Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2433333Z",
                                            "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:42.5233333Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2433333Z",
                                            "status": "failed",
                                            "rank": 3,
                                            "issues": [
                                                {
                                                    "issueType": "Error",
                                                    "message": "Failed rmRF: Command failed: rd /s /q \"D:\\a\\r1\\a\"\nThe process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.\r\n",
                                                    "data": {
                                                        "type": "error",
                                                        "logFileLineNumber": "16"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "task": {
                                                "id": "5e1e3830-fbfb-11e5-aab1-090c92bc4988",
                                                "name": "ExtractFiles",
                                                "version": "1.200.0"
                                            },
                                            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/37/environments/37/deployPhases/41/tasks/6/logs"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": 0,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "eae0669a-e2ad-530b-f008-4105bdd5d304",
                                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                                            "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2433333Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2466667Z",
                                            "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2433333Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2466667Z",
                                            "status": "skipped",
                                            "rank": 4,
                                            "issues": [],
                                            "task": {
                                                "id": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                                                "name": "PowerShell",
                                                "version": "2.200.0"
                                            },
                                            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                            "logUrl": "",
                                            "resultCode": "Evaluating: succeeded()\r\nResult: False\r\n"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": 7,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "cfbbae06-d8fc-4d1e-a79b-f920071e5481",
                                            "name": "Finalize Job",
                                            "dateStarted": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.25Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2566667Z",
                                            "startTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.25Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2022-07-22T07:46:46.2566667Z",
                                            "status": "succeeded",
                                            "percentComplete": 100,
                                            "rank": 5,
                                            "issues": [],
                                            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
                                            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/37/environments/37/deployPhases/41/tasks/7/logs"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "manualInterventions": [],
                            "startedOn": "2022-07-22T07:46:36.16Z"
                        }
                    ],...,
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {},
    "variableGroups": [],
    "artifacts": [
        {
            "sourceId": "c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6:221",
            "type": "Build",
            "alias": "_buildartifact",
            "definitionReference": {
                "artifactSourceDefinitionUrl": {
                    "id": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=b1cc953d-b564-4eec-a222-84393e4406b1&projectId=c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6&definitionId=221",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "branches": {
                    "id": "main",
                    "name": "main"
                },
                "buildUri": {
                    "id": "vstfs:///Build/Build/2119",
                    "name": null
                },
                "definition": {
                    "id": "221",
                    "name": "buildartifact"
                },
                "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                    "id": "False",
                    "name": "False"
                },
                "IsXamlBuildArtifactType": {
                    "id": "False",
                    "name": null
                },
                "project": {
                    "id": "c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6",
                    "name": "xxx"
                },
                "repository.provider": {
                    "id": "TfsGit",
                    "name": null
                },
                "repository": {
                    "id": "a433b7a0-a23c-4c18-9d14-d0859568dec3",
                    "name": "buildartifact"
                },
                "requestedFor": {
                    "id": "15365687987",
                    "name": null
                },
                "requestedForId": {
                    "id": "af91e22a-cc35-4c8e-8af3-f49c4a1b9b6a",
                    "name": null
                },
                "sourceVersion": {
                    "id": "3d0b3f71bc2391b95325fabb0b3b48a8ade2014f",
                    "name": null
                },
                "version": {
                    "id": "2119",
                    "name": "20220722.1"
                },
                "artifactSourceVersionUrl": {
                    "id": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=b1cc953d-b564-4eec-a222-84393e4406b1&projectId=c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6&buildId=2119",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "branch": {
                    "id": "refs/heads/main",
                    "name": "refs/heads/main"
                }
            },
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isRetained": true
        }
    ],
    "releaseDefinition": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "DownloadArtifactAndShow",
        "path": "\\",
        "projectReference": null,
        "url": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/definitions/9",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/definitions/9"
            },
            "web": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_release?definitionId=9"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

You can see that all of the tasks' situations are in the response. The status of the task is also there.

For a build pipeline, no public API to get the status of the task directly, you need to analyze the logs in the response to get the status of the task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0